# Swift - Singleton without global access

Tags: swift, xcode, singleton

I want to create a Swift Singleton without global access. The pattern which I want to create is to assure that always just one instance of a class exists but this class should not be accessible over the usual global `MyClass.shared` syntax. The reason for this is that I want the class to be fully and correctly testable (which is not really possible with global Singletons). I will then use dependency injection to pass the single instance from viewcontroller to viewcontroller. So the "access" issue is solved without a global static instance.

What I could do is to do basically - nothing. Just create a normal class and trust on the discipline of all developers to not instantiate this class again and again but use it only injected as a dependency. But I would rather have some compiler enforced pattern which prohibits this.

So the requirement is:

- assure during compile time that only one instance of a class is instantiated
- no global access
- the assurance that only one class is instantiated should not be enforced during Unit Tests, so it's possible to test it correctly

My first attempt to solve this was something like this:

[image]

```
class WebService {
    private static var instances = 0

    init() {
        assertSingletonInstance()
    }

    private func assertSingletonInstance() {
        #if DEBUG
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isUnitTestRunning.rawValue) == false {
            WebService.instances += 1
            assert(WebService.instances == 1, "Do not create multiple instances of this class. Get it thru the shared dependencies in your module.")
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Remark: passing an argument during launch creates a user defaults value which can be checked during runtime. This is how I know that the current run is a unit test.

Generally this pattern works quite good. My only problem with this - I have to duplicate this code over and over again for every possible singleton. Which is not nice. I would prefer a reusable solution.

### Singleton Protocol Extension

One solution for this was to create a Protocol Extension:

```
protocol Singleton {
    static var instances: Int { get set }
    func assertSingletonInstance()
}

extension Singleton {
    // Call this assertion in init() to check for multiple instances of one type.
    func assertSingletonInstance() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isUnitTestRunning.rawValue) == false {
            Self.instances += 1
            assert(Self.instances == 1, "Do not create multiple instances of this class. Get it thru the shared dependencies in your module.")
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

And then use it in this way:

```
class WebService: Singleton {)
    static var instances = 0

    init() {
        assertSingletonInstance()
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `instances` variable is not `private`. So someone could just set this variable to 0 before instantiating the class and the check would not work anymore.

### Singleton Base Class

The other attempt was a `Singleton` base class. In this case a `private static var instances` can be used.

```
class Singleton {
    private static var instances = 0

    required init() {
        assertSingletonInstance()
    }

    private func assertSingletonInstance() {
        #if DEBUG
            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isUnitTestRunning.rawValue) == false {
                Singleton.instances += 1
                assert(Singleton.instances == 1, "Do not create multiple instances of this class. Get it thru the shared dependencies in your module.")
            }
        #endif
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is - it does not work. Incrementing `Singleton.instance` adds 1 to the `static instances` of the `Singleton` type and not to the class which derives from the `Singleton` base class.

Now I am left with either doing *nothing* and relying on the discipline and understanding of all developers or at least use the protocol extension with `internal` or `public` access.

A sample implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/DarkoDamjanovic/SolidRock.AppTemplate.iOS).

Maybe someone has better ideas for a really clean solution to this problem. I appreciate any hints or a discussion about it. Thanks.

Comment: What if you put all your dependencies in a separate module, which builds a library/framework, with only a single exposed "Globals" protocol, with a default instance. The globals protocol provides access to all dependencies (db, web apis, w/e), which could all have `internal` initializers. From there, it would be easy to make a "MockGlobals" object, which is set to that global `instance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an atomic flag (for thread safety) to mark the singleton as being instantiated:

```
class Singleton {

    static private var hasInstance = atomic_flag()

    init() {
        // use precondition() instead of assert() if you want the crashes to happen in Release builds too
        assert(!atomic_flag_test_and_set(&type(of: self).hasInstance), "Singleton here, don't instantiate me more than once!!!")
    }

    deinit {
        atomic_flag_clear(&type(of: self).hasInstance)
    }
}
```

You mark the singleton as allocated in `init`, and you reset the flag in `deinit`. This allows you on one hand to have only one instance (if the original instance doesn't get deallocated), and on the other hand to have multiple instances, as long as they don't overlap.

**App code**: assuming that you'll keep a reference to the singleton, somewhere, that you inject downstream, then `deinit` should never be called, which leads to only one possible allocation.

**Unit testing code**: if the unit tests properly do the cleanup (the tested singleton gets deallocated after every test), then there will be only one living instance at a certain point in time, which won't trigger the assertion failure.

Comment: You would need to synchronize that, because you could end up with multiple objects due to the race condition

Comment: Good point, @Alexander, updated the answer to include thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Cristik's answer:

This is a really nice solution! The `type(of: self)` solves the base class problem. And releasing the thing in deinit is a great idea to allow the whole thing in unit tests. You are right - I keep the references of all the Singletons "upstream" and inject them afterwards. Perfect.

I have created a template based on this ideas with a serial queue for the possible race condition problem. I assume this is a better solution then the atomic_flag and more "Swiftish".

Playground code:

```
import Foundation

class Singleton {
    static private var instances = 0

    // Sync the access to instances
    private var serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourcompany.app.singletoncheck")

    init() {
        serialQueue.sync {
            type(of: self).instances += 1
            assert(type(of: self).instances == 1, "Do not create multiple instances of this class living at the same time.")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        type(of: self).instances = 0
    }
}

class Derived: Singleton {

}

var a: Derived? = Derived()
//a = nil // release to prevent the assertion from failing
var b: Derived? = Derived() // assertion fails here, works!
```

And here is an even more interesting solution which can be used everywhere without any special knowledge and no assertions at all. It uses a failable initializer.

Playground code:

```
import Foundation

class Singleton {
    static private var instances = 0

    // Sync the access to instances
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourcompany.app.singletoncheck")

    // This failable initializer assures that at the same time only one instance of this class exists.
    init?() {
        var singleInstance = false
        serialQueue.sync {
            type(of: self).instances += 1
            if type(of: self).instances == 1 {
                singleInstance = true
            }
        }
        if !singleInstance {
            return nil
        }
    }

    deinit {
        serialQueue.sync {
            type(of: self).instances = 0
        }
    }
}

class Derived: Singleton {
    var a = 0
    func increment() {
        serialQueue.sync {
            a += 1
            print(a)
        }
    }
}

var a = Derived()
a?.increment() // call to synchonized version of increment
//a = nil //either a or b is alive
var b = Derived()

print (a) //prints Optional(__lldb_expr_15.Derived)
print (b) //prints nil
```

This is in my opinion the "real" Singleton, described by the Gang of four. Global access was only an implementation detail at that time.

So in comparison to the usual Singleton pattern it:

- has no global access
- is a reusable pattern
- all shared mutable state could be synchronised (if taken care of)
- fully testable in Unit Tests

So it has all the advantages of a Singleton, but without the usual problems.

Comment: Note that you also need to ensure thread safetiness in deinit.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, you might not need it, since you'd only end up in unit tests to execute `deinit`, and unit tests usually run on main.

Comment: I added a second variant without assertion and generally usable everywhere, with a failable initializer. In this case the `deinit` has to be synchronised as well, right. And the syncQueue can then be used also by derived classes to sync their access.